# VBA unable to read other workbooks from same folder

Tags: vba, file-not-found

This is with reference to my previous questions that has been solved but come out another problems: [VBA unable to read files after closing and reopen excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396560/vba-unable-to-read-files-after-closing-and-reopen-excel/57397696#57397696)

All 3 files are in same folder and are opened. It giving me Run time error 9: Subscript out of range.

```
For i = 1 To rows 
Workbooks(destination).Worksheets(destinationSheet).Cells( destinationSheetRow + i, Cells(8, j + 3)) = Workbooks(source).Worksheets(sourceSheet).Cells(sourceSheetRow + i, Cells(4, j + 3))
Next i
```

When I did debugging, both destination and source are the full path and sheet name are correct. Not sure what the problems. Thanks

Comment: Q: Not sure what the problems.  A:  `Subscript out of range`.  The problem isn't the "folder" or "filepath": it's "i" or "j" (or "destinationSheetRow+i" or "8")!  One or more of your indexes is "out of range" at some point in your loop!

Comment: That nested `Cells` in `.Cells( destinationSheetRow + i, Cells(8, j + 3))` and in `.Cells(sourceSheetRow + i, Cells(4, j + 3))` looks problematic. `Cells` needs a column index as the second argument. Is that what you're going for?

Comment: During debugging i print all the 8 values are correct: 1. destination is the full path name, 2. destinationSheet the sheet name, 3. destinationSheetRow + i is the row ref number eg. 8, 4. Cells(8, j + 3) is the column ref from the file mapping eg. 2. Same for source file but different values.

Comment: Check for trailing spaces on the end of the sheet names. If needed, ditch the cells portion of the line and just verify that you can access workbook and worksheet.

Comment: _1. destination is the full path name_ and that is your problem, use file name without path.

Comment: @paulsm4 there is a problem with cell indexes (nested Cells inside Cells - as explained in the second comment) - but no, wrong indexes do not result in _Subscript out of range_. This one is caused by using full path as `Workbooks` colllection index.

Comment: paulsm4 I have tested nested Cells value worked 
@BrakNicku Thanks i have solved by giving it file name only. I use the full path is to check if file exist and open

Answer (score 0):

Thanks BrakNicku for the comment. I created a new variable to extract file name from the full path as I was using the full path is to check if file exist and open.